# Install vagrant plugin on archlinux

Tags: vagrant, arch-linux

I am trying to install vagrant plugin in ArchLinux and get error Marshal.load reentered at marshal_load. Here is output with debug on:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmananger --debug
 INFO global: Vagrant version: 1.9.4
 INFO global: Ruby version: 2.2.5
 INFO global: RubyGems version: 2.4.5.1
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_TILIX_ID="0bec956b-314e-4c6a-a2e2-14727c07c7ab"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_ZSH="/usr/share/oh-my-zsh"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID="this-is-deprecated"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_COLORTERM="truecolor"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_LSCOLORS="Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID="1173"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_GDM_LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_SESSION_MANAGER="local/archerite:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/975,unix/archerite:/tmp/.ICE-unix/975"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE="/etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_OLDPWD="/home/gerassum/Projects/ogsm-app"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_DISPLAY=":1"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_XDG_SESSION_TYPE="x11"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_XDG_SEAT="seat0"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_USERNAME="gerassum"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_PAGER="less"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV__="/usr/bin/vagrant"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_ENV="1"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_TERM="xterm-256color"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_VERSION="2"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_XAUTHORITY="/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="gnome"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_GDMSESSION="gnome"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_VTE_VERSION="4803"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_SHLVL="1"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_LOGNAME="gerassum"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_LESS="-R"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_HOME="/home/gerassum"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_USER="gerassum"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_XDG_VTNR="2"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_EMBEDDED_DIR="/opt/vagrant/embedded"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_LS_COLORS="rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_JOURNAL_STREAM="9:18733"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_XDG_SESSION_ID="c3"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_DESKTOP_SESSION="gnome"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_WINDOWPATH="2"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_MAIL="/var/spool/mail/gerassum"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_PWD="/home/gerassum"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_SHELL="/bin/zsh"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_EXECUTABLE="/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/bin/vagrant"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_NO_PLUGINS="1"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_DISABLE_PLUGIN_INIT="1"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_LOG="debug"
 INFO global: Plugins:
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/hosts/arch/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Arch host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/hosts/windows/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Windows host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/hosts/freebsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: FreeBSD host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/hosts/null/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: null host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/hosts/slackware/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Slackware host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/hosts/darwin/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Mac OS X host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/hosts/linux/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Linux host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/hosts/redhat/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Red Hat Enterprise Linux host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/hosts/gentoo/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Gentoo host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/hosts/suse/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SUSE host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/hosts/bsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: BSD host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: VirtualBox provider
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/providers/docker/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: docker-provider
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/providers/hyperv/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Hyper-V provider
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/provisioners/puppet/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: puppet
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/provisioners/file/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: file
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/provisioners/shell/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: shell
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/provisioners/cfengine/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: CFEngine Provisioner
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/provisioners/ansible/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ansible
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/provisioners/docker/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: docker
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/provisioners/chef/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: chef
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/provisioners/salt/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: salt
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/status/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: status command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/up/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: up command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/box/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: box command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/validate/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: validate command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/plugin/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: plugin command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/halt/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: halt command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/powershell/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: powershell command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/reload/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: reload command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/version/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: version command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/destroy/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: destroy command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/list-commands/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: list-commands command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/rdp/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: rdp command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/ssh/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/help/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: help command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/cap/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: cap command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/provision/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: provision command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/push/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: push command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/port/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: port command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/resume/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: resume command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/provider/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: provider command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/global-status/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: global-status command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/ssh_config/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh-config command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/login/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: vagrant-login
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/snapshot/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: snapshot command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/suspend/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: suspend command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/package/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: package command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/init/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: init command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/dragonflybsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: DragonFly BSD guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/arch/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Arch guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/windows/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Windows guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/debian/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Debian guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/freebsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: FreeBSD guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/fedora/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Fedora guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/pld/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: PLD Linux guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/trisquel/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Trisquel guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/omnios/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OmniOS guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/atomic/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Atomic Host guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/openbsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OpenBSD guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/coreos/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: CoreOS guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/ubuntu/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Ubuntu guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/esxi/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ESXi guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/netbsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: NetBSD guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/funtoo/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Funtoo guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/mint/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Mint guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/slackware/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Slackware guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/darwin/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Darwin guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/photon/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: VMware Photon guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/linux/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Linux guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/amazon/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Amazon Linux guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/redhat/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Red Hat Enterprise Linux guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/tinycore/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: TinyCore Linux guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/elementary/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Elementary guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/gentoo/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Gentoo guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/solaris/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Solaris guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/nixos/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: NixOS guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/solaris11/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Solaris 11 guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/suse/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SUSE guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/bsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: BSD-based guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/smartos/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SmartOS guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/pushes/local-exec/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: local-exec
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/pushes/noop/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: noop
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/pushes/ftp/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ftp
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/pushes/heroku/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: heroku
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/pushes/atlas/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: atlas
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/kernel_v1/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: kernel
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/synced_folders/rsync/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: RSync synced folders
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: NFS synced folders
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/synced_folders/smb/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SMB synced folders
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh communicator
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/communicators/winrm/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: winrm communicator
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/communicators/winssh/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: windows ssh communicator
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/kernel_v2/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: kernel
DEBUG global: Plugin loading is currently disabled.
 INFO vagrant: `vagrant` invoked: ["plugin", "install", "vagrant-hostmananger", "--debug"]
DEBUG vagrant: Creating Vagrant environment
 INFO environment: Environment initialized (#<Vagrant::Environment:0x000000029ab530>)
 INFO environment:   - cwd: /home/gerassum
 INFO environment: Home path: /home/gerassum/.vagrant.d
DEBUG environment: Effective local data path: 
 WARN environment: No local data path is set. Local data cannot be stored.
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_plugins_loaded
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: environment_plugins_loaded #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000002821cf0>
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_load
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: environment_load #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x000000026b7270>
 INFO cli: CLI: [] "plugin" ["install", "vagrant-hostmananger"]
DEBUG cli: Invoking command class: VagrantPlugins::CommandPlugin::Command::Root ["install", "vagrant-hostmananger"]
DEBUG root: Invoking command class: VagrantPlugins::CommandPlugin::Command::Install ["vagrant-hostmananger"]
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:home, :root]
DEBUG loader: Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning
DEBUG push: finalizing
 INFO host: Autodetecting host type for [#<Vagrant::Environment: /home/gerassum>]
DEBUG host: Trying: arch
 INFO host: Detected: arch!
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action:  #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000002336218>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::CommandPlugin::Action::InstallGem:0x000000026b61b8>
 INFO interface: info: Installing the 'vagrant-hostmananger' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installing the 'vagrant-hostmananger' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
DEBUG bundler: Dependency list for installation: [<Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="vagrant-hostmananger" requirements="> 0">]
DEBUG bundler: Enabling user defined remote RubyGems sources
DEBUG bundler: Enabling default remote RubyGems sources
DEBUG bundler: Adding source - https://rubygems.org/
DEBUG bundler: Adding source - https://gems.hashicorp.com/
ERROR warden: Error occurred: Marshal.load reentered at marshal_load
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Calling recover: #<VagrantPlugins::CommandPlugin::Action::InstallGem:0x000000026b61b8>
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_unload
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: environment_unload #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000002a49c08>
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source.rb:192:in `load': Marshal.load reentered at marshal_load (RuntimeError)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source.rb:192:in `load_specs'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:335:in `block in validate_configured_sources!'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each_source'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:333:in `validate_configured_sources!'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:268:in `internal_install'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:106:in `install'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:62:in `block in install_plugin'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:72:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:72:in `install_plugin'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:29:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:14:in `action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:32:in `block in execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:66:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:308:in `cli'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/bin/vagrant:127:in `<main>'
```

Any suggestions? I am not familiar with Ruby, so don`t know where to look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was seeing similar errors as well as segfaults in vagrant's bundled ruby.

Downgrading from vagrant-substrate from 605.0566498-2 to 599.d7cedfe-2 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this same issue, and Tim's solve (downgrading vagrant-substrate to 599.*) fixed it for me as well.

Just wanted to add to all this that I upgraded to vagrant-substrate-718.205e64c-2-x86_64 today, and the issue seems to be resolved.